# How to insert slide range to mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

How to insert slide range to mysql ?

When press `submit` i want to insert slide range into `mysql`.

I try this code but not work!

How can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/b63u9krv/3/

PHP

```
<?PHP
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO table_name(slide_value)VALUES('$value_data')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);  
}
?>
```

script

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
range: "min",
value: 0,
min: 0,
max: 700,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#value_data" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
}
});
$( "#value_data" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score -1):

Code should be:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <div id="slider-range-min"></div>
    <!--missing input field added-->
    <input type="hidden" id="value_data" name="value_data"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK"/>
</form>

<?PHP
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) 
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO table_name(slide_value)VALUES('".$_POST['value_data']."')";//updated
    $result=mysql_query($sql);  
}
?>
```

### Updates in code description

---

1. you are updating value of `value_data` field, so this should be in
   form while you are submitting it.
2. Instead of using `$value_data` while inserting you should use
   `$_POST['value_data']`.